# Updating information in a TableView using a Timer

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView that displays a list of cities and the current time in those cities, which I update using a Timer.

I am starting initializing the time like this:

```
clockTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: true) { [self] t in
    let myTime = Date().formatted(date: .omitted, time: .standard)

    for i in 0 ..< cities.count {
        let cityGMTDiff = cities[i].gmtDiff
        let overallGMTDiff = cityGMTDiff - myGMTDiff
        let cityTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(Double(overallGMTDiff) * 3600.0).formatted(date: .omitted, time: .standard)
        cities[i].time = cityTime
    }
    citiesTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I am also implementing the ability to delete a row of the TableView using with this delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        cities.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        citiesTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

What's happening, though, is that when I try to delete a row the timer updates the TableView, preventing me from completing the delete row operation.

I have tried to invalidate the timer as soon as I select a row, however I suspect that's not the proper way to handle this.

Comment: Don't calculate the time for every city every time.  Store the time zone for their city and use that to format the output based on the time in your timezone.  Then if you wish to follow this approach, use the timer's action to refresh the tableView, first checking if it is editing and if so skipping the update

Comment: @flanker, I apologize if I don't understand your reply. I do store the timezone for each city in the TableView (well, the gmtDifference, which is the difference between the city and GMT.) As soon as I try to swipe to delete a row the swipe operation cancels when the timer triggers.

Comment: I suppose I could add a button to remove the selected row – not using a swipe to delete operation – but I would like to understand how to properly do that.

Comment: @psb add the timer to your custom cell. This would allow the cell to update itself independently

Comment: @LeoDabus I was going to suggest that as well in my answer but it makes it more difficult to keep the timers in sync so that all of the rows change at the same time.

Comment: @HangarRash you can schedule the fireDate to the next even second or if you are not displaying seconds even minute. This would also save battery life reducing the number of times the timer fires updating the UI only when needed..

Comment: This would also allow it to be in sync with the device's clock.

Comment: @LeoDabus, lot's to unpack and analyze.
I'll try to wrap my head around this suggestion and consider if it will work for my needs.
Thank you!

Comment: @psb this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62844180/2303865) might help you scheduling the fireDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the issue is the call to `reloadData` every 0.5 seconds. That prevents very little interaction with the table view.

There are a few possible solutions that I can think of.

1. When the timer triggers, get the cells for the visible rows. Iterate the cells and tell each cell to update itself with the current time. This uses much less overhead and it avoids the use of `reloadData` and allows the user to swipe-to-delete a row.
2. Do what the standard Clock app does on the World Clock tab. Only allow deletions while in Edit mode. And during Edit mode, you don't show the time which means you don't call `reloadData` while in Edit mode.

Comment: Thank you @HangarRash.
I will consider that, along with the behavior I would like the user to be presented with.